# apex application page not found

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I created an empty application with project sample database in apex with administration and access control features.

Every time I create a new page for a table and want to run it, the page does not appear in navigation menu and when I run it from page editor an error occurs. (Report, master Report and etc.)

This problem does not happen in another applications I have.
Does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: Is it new installation of APEX? Which Version? Does this issue happening only in one application or all applications?

Comment: Yes. It is on a Oracle VM and I think it's 19.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't happen in the other program I have. But I do not understand the reason for this at all.

Comment: If it's happening in all applications on that APEX Instance, it could be issue with APEX Installation. Try installing APEX again. I have never seen such an error where page exists in the application, but APEX throws this error when try to run the page.

Comment: Sounds like something went wrong with the application creation process (perhaps an error occurred) or afterward to the application metadata (corrupted somehow). If you create another new application, does it work fine? If so, use that one! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something went wrong with the application creation process (perhaps an error occurred) or afterward to the application metadata (corrupted somehow). 
When I created another new application, it worked fine.